# Office add-ins user authentication with SSO

Tags: office-js, office-addins

I'm building a Web Excel Add-in using the Office.js library.

One issue is related with the license/authentication of users. I'd like the add-in to get the user's domain and compare it with my white list.

The [documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/sso-in-office-add-ins) regarding Single Sign On indicates that this feature is in preview, not accepted in AppSource and should not be used in production.

The alternative seems to be Authorization with Azure Active Directory, but how to get started? Can anyone share a few code samples?

I'm still in exploratory mode, so thanks for your generous feedback.

Comment: Does [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph-without-sso) and the articles that it links to help?

Comment: @RickKirkham thanks for helping. My Linux server runs on PHP. Do you know where I can find code samples for performing the licensing as described? I just need to get started!

Answer (score 0):

An add-in is mainly just a web app, so I think that if you search for something like `connect (or access) azure active directory from PHP` you'll find information about how to do this. One possible wrinkle: The AAD login page will not open in an iframe and the task pane of an add-in is an iframe when the add-in is running on Excel Online. To deal with that situation, you need to use the Dialog API. See this article for details: [Authenticate and authorize with the Office dialog API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/auth-with-office-dialog-api).

Comment: thanks, I'm researching, but all I find seems a bit old, so I guess add-in development for office isn't progressing much, is it? Anyway, if I can't figure out how to do this, will it be possible to redirect the user to a password-protected page in my website, or will that page also not load inside an i-frame?

Comment: I found out that the task pane loads a web page, even with Excel online. Now, it would be much better to reach the user's context, like the O365 domain, mail and onedrive. With google sheet add-ins this is possible, is it also with Excel? Thanks for helping